# Robot stop while moving

Tags: ros-noetic, teb-local-planner

I'm using teb_local_planner for my diff drive robot. There is an issue where cmd_vel speed suddenly becomes 0 during navigation.

https://youtu.be/nexkATOatVE

1. When using navigation, a phenomenon occurs where the speed becomes 0 in the middle, as shown in the video above. I'm curious about the solution.
2. I wonder if it is possible to apply different speeds when rotating in place and when rotating while moving.

here is my teb_local_planner_params.yaml

```
TebLocalPlannerROS:
  odom_topic: odom
  map_frame: map
    
  # Trajectory
  teb_autosize: True
  dt_ref: 0.3
  dt_hysteresis: 0.1
  global_plan_overwrite_orientation: True
  allow_init_with_backwards_motion: False
  max_global_plan_lookahead_dist: 0.4
  feasibility_check_no_poses: 5
  
  # Robot
  max_vel_x: 0.18
  max_vel_x_backwards: 0.15
  max_vel_y: 0.0
  max_vel_theta: 0.8
  acc_lim_x: 0.3
  acc_lim_y: 0.0
  acc_lim_theta: 1.2

  min_turning_radius: 0.0
  wheelbase: 0.0

  footprint_model:
    types: "polygon"
    vertices: [[-0.2, -0.17], [-0.2, 0.17], [0.3, 0.17], [0.3, -0.17]]

  # GoalTolerance
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.07
  free_goal_vel: False
  complete_global_plan: True
    
  # Obstacles
  min_obstacle_dist: 0.19
  inflation_dist: 0.01
  include_costmap_obstacles: False
  costmap_obstacles_behind_robot_dist: 1.5
  obstacle_poses_affected: 15
  costmap_converter_plugin: ""
  costmap_converter_spin_thread: True
  costmap_converter_rate: 5

  # Optimization
    
  no_inner_iterations: 5
  no_outer_iterations: 4
  optimization_activate: True
  optimization_verbose: False
  penalty_epsilon: 0.1
  weight_max_vel_x: 1
  weight_max_vel_y: 0
  weight_max_vel_theta: 1
  weight_acc_lim_x: 1
  weight_acc_lim_y: 0
  weight_acc_lim_theta: 1
  weight_kinematics_nh: 1000
  weight_kinematics_forward_drive: 1000
  weight_kinematics_turning_radius: 1
  weight_optimaltime: 1
  weight_shortest_path: 100
  weight_obstacle: 50
  weight_dynamic_obstacle: 10 # not in use yet
  selection_alternative_time_cost: False # not in use yet
  weight_viapoint: 1
  weight_adapt_factor: 2

  # Homotopy Class Planner

  enable_homotopy_class_planning: True
  enable_multithreading: True
  simple_exploration: False
  max_number_classes: 4
  roadmap_graph_no_samples: 15
  roadmap_graph_area_width: 5
  h_signature_prescaler: 0.5 
  h_signature_threshold: 0.1
  obstacle_keypoint_offset: 0.1
  obstacle_heading_threshold: 0.45
  visualize_hc_graph: False
```